# Odd HashMap lifetime requirement on key when value is a new type wrapper

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand how changing the value type in a HashMap from `&'t str` to `Value<'t>(&'t str)` leads to a stricter requirement on the `Key` type passed in to `get` below.

```rust
#![allow(dead_code, unused)]
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Key<'t>(&'t str);

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Value<'t>(&'t str);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Map1<'t>(HashMap<Key<'t>, &'t str>);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Map2<'t>(HashMap<Key<'t>, Value<'t>>);

impl<'t> Map1<'t> {
    fn get<'map>(&'map self, key: &Key<'_>) -> Option<&'map str> {
        self.0.get(key).map(|x| *x)
    }
}

impl<'t> Map2<'t> {
    fn get<'map>(&'map self, key: &Key<'_>) -> Option<&'map Value<'t>> {
        // Doesn't work, says:    -------- help: add explicit lifetime `'map` to the type of `key`: `&Key<'map>`
        self.0.get(key)
    }
}
```

In `Map1` with value type `&'t str` it's fine to pass in a `Key` with any lifetime, whereas in `Map2` with value type `Value<'t>` (a new type wrapper around `&'t str`) it is no longer fine and I'm expected to pass a key whose inner lifetime is as long as the map itself.

Could you help me understand why this the case?

Is there anything I can do to make the new type wrapped `Value(&str)` work the same as a `&str`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two `get` implementations are not equivalent:

```rs
        self.0.get(key).map(|x| *x)
        // vs
        self.0.get(key)
```

what the `map` is doing is essentially a `copy()`. What would be the type of the `Map1::map` method without that copy?

```rs
impl<'t> Map1<'t> {
    fn get<'map>(&'map self, key: &Key<'_>) -> Option<&'map &'t str> {
        self.0.get(key)
    }
}
```

... which gives you the same error.

So, what you really need is to copy that `Value`, e.g. like this:

```rs
impl<'t> Map2<'t> {
    fn get<'map>(&'map self, key: &Key<'_>) -> Option<Value<'t>> {
        self.0.get(key).copied()
    }
}
```

If you want to not do that, then naturally you *will* need to change the lifetime declaration compared to `Map1`.

Comment: Perfect. Adding `.copied()` to both `get`s and changing the second to return `Option<Value<'t>>` did the trick.

Comment: The strict requirement on the key still seemed wrong in the borrow case: why does it matter what the lifetime of the key is in `get(key)` when it isn't kept? It turns out this is a known issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80389 . I didn't quite manage to tease it out into a good example for this question, but that's what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Interesting! I had the feeling that my answer stepped around a lingering problem in your question, thus the handwave-y last sentence... I'm afraid I can't help you with that bug though :P

Comment: Adding `let key = Key(unsafe { &*(key.0 as *const str) })` to `Map2::get` worked. This creates an unbounded lifetime for the internal reference. I believe that's safe, but it's my first use of unsafe, and I'm starting to feel like a magician.

Comment: I haven't really done unsafe, but I would be careful with using it to extend lifetimes like this. "working around the borrow checker" is one of the things I understand you're not supposed to do with unsafe. (but then again, my understanding of this is not very deep)